# Upload file with BOM encoding

Tags: c#, unicode, encoding, byte-order-mark

I need to upload/create a file on an FTP server with `UCS-2 LE BOM` encoding.  I'm using C#.

Based on [Microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.unicodeencoding.-ctor?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netcore-3.1#System_Text_UnicodeEncoding__ctor_System_Boolean_System_Boolean_), I have to use `UnicodeEncoding` with `bigEndian:false` and `byteOrderMark:true`. Here is the code:

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    client.Encoding = new UnicodeEncoding(false, true);
    client.Credentials = myCredentials;
    client.UploadString(path, WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile, myCsvInString);
}
```

The created file on the FTP server actually has `UCS-2 Little Endian`. For test purposes, I tried to switch the `byteOrderMark` to `false` and I got the same result.

Why? What am I missing?

I know that I could add `'\uFEFF'` but why isn't it done automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The interface and description of `UnicodeEncoding` could be improved regarding the handling of the byte order mark. `UnicodeEncoding` has a *byte order mark* attribute but the only method (aside from `Equals` and `GetHashCode`) using it is `GetPreamble`. All other methods and in particular the core method `GetBytes` don't.

The idea is to ensure the byte order mark is only ever written at the beginning of a file. `UnicodeEncoding` has no knowledge of the context. So it's up to the caller to add the preamble if needed (ie. byte order mark).

Based on this concept, `WebClient.UploadString` cannot assume it's uploading a file. It might be some other Unicode content. So it doesn't add the preamble.

You will have to add the preamble yourself. `UnicodeEncoding.GetPreamble` will return it.